# sql copy reference on data from one table to another

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a task to create an online-text editor and I have a problem with copying of texts. In my database I have following tables:

1. Project, that contains 3 columns: prnr (projectnumber(primary key), title (of project), and author);
2. Text, that contains 4 columns: textId (primary key), prnr (foreign key  from table project), textOrder (index of text….for example: when index is 1 than it will be the first abstract in the project) and textValue (the content of the abstract).

The user will choose his project and it will be opened in another page. On this opened page must be a button that will give the user an opportunity to copy a separate abstract into another project.

The problem is that it must be copied not a plain text (I mean not simply choose text from one table and copy it to another)but it must be copied a reference of this abstract (when the user will copy this abstract to another project and will make changes in it, the changes must appear in both projects).

Do you know any sql-statements (my sql) that allow to copy a reference of the table or how to copy reference on data from one table to another?

Comment: What data is in the abstract? Where is it stored?

Comment: I think you need an associative table between project and text so that multiple projects can reference the same "text" and the same text can be used in multiple projects.  This way you change the text in table text and the "Pointers" (associatve records) still remain and all projects using those pointers have their text updated.  The problem you have here is one of cardinality.  A project has multiple text records a single text record may be used in multiple projects thus a many-to-many that must be resolved though associative (junction) tables.